# Usage of backoffLimit/maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm launching Spring batch jobs from SCDF which is running in OPenshift environment. I wanted to limit the POD restarts to 1 when a Spring batch job fails (instead of default limit 6).
So I added the backoffLimit as 1 to scdf-server-config.yaml. But when the job fails the POD still gets restarted for 6 times. Whats the correct property or correct to add backoffLimit in SCDF. Even maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts doesn't work.

Below is what I tried.

**scdf-config.yaml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      task:
        platform:
          kubernetes:
            accounts:
              k8sp:
                limits:
                    memory: 512Mi
                    cpu: 1
            entry-point-style: exec
            image-pull-policy: always
            backoffLimit: 1
            maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts: 1
```

**Update 1:**

I gave proper indents in server-config.yaml of scdf server as mentioned below and tried adding the Kubernetes deployer properties to my batch application.properties as below,

**scdf-config.yaml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      task:
        platform:
          kubernetes:
            accounts:
              default:
                limits:
                    memory: 1024Mi
                    cpu: 2
                entry-point-style: exec
                image-pull-policy: always
                backoffLimit: 0
                max-terminated-error-restarts: 0
```

BatchJob Project application.properties

```
spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.backoff-limit=0
spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.max-terminated-error-restarts=0
spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.max-crash-loop-back-off-restarts=0
```

Still when the job fails the pod restarts for 6 times. What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Those values aren't indented correctly. They need to be something like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      task:
        platform:
          kubernetes:
            accounts:
              k8sp:
                limits:
                    memory: 512Mi
                    cpu: 1
                entry-point-style: exec
                image-pull-policy: always
                backoffLimit: 1
                maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts: 1
```

Comment: I tried with correct indents now, But I still see the pods are started right after the failure though the backoffLimit & maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts is 1. Should this configurations placed at SCDF Server config level or bath application level?